# Start of line "^" regular expression syntax not working for findstr in Windows?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, command

I want `findstr` to match strings from the beginning of the line (`^`). However, as can be seen from the following example, it doesn't work:

```
C:\Users\bd6164>dir | findstr /R ^3
    22-11-2018  08:43    <DIR>          .
    22-11-2018  08:43    <DIR>          ..
    22-11-2018  07:58    <DIR>          3D Objects
                  16 Dir(s)  219.434.221.568 bytes free
```

I've also tested matching the end of line (`$`) and it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` *Circumflex Accent* has a [special meaning](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in Windows command line (and in a *batch script* as well):

> **Escape Character**
>
> ```
>   ^  Escape character
> ```
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
>   treated as ordinary text.

Use

```
dir | findstr /R ^^3
```

or (escape using "Double Quotes")

```
dir | findstr /R "^3"
```

**Examples**:

```
dir /ad | findstr /R ^^3
```

> ```
> 31.01.2018  15:14    <DIR>          odds and ends
> 31.05.2019  21:04    <DIR>          SF
> 30.06.2015  22:23    <DIR>          xxx
> ```

```
dir /ad | findstr /R "^3"
```

> ```
> 31.01.2018  15:14    <DIR>          odds and ends
> 31.05.2019  21:04    <DIR>          SF
> 30.06.2015  22:23    <DIR>          xxx
> ```